# Fragment caching increasing database queries

Tags: cache, transient

While implementing fragment caching on a wordpress site by using the technique described here: http://css-tricks.com/wordpress-fragment-caching-revisited/ I found that it seems to actually increase queries.

I have now cached many fragments on the page, and (in my local environment) I get 294 queries in 0.764 seconds (calculated with `get_num_queries()` and `timer_stop(0)`).

One snippet I've cached is the menu. If I remove fragment caching from it, I get:
292 queries in 0.736 seconds.

If I remove fragment caching from my search from:
290 queries in 0.862 seconds.

And if I remove more queries:
287 queries in 0.783 seconds.

So, what's happening here? Fragment caching is definitely working, but is it having a positive effect? Also, is it ok to have actually more queries with fragment caching than without?

In `functions.php` I have:

```
function fragment_cache($key, $ttl, $function) {
  if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    call_user_func($function);
    return;
  }
  $key = apply_filters('fragment_cache_prefix', 'fragment_cache_').$key;
  $output = get_transient($key);
  if ( empty($output) ) {
    ob_start();
    call_user_func($function);
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    set_transient($key, $output, $ttl);
  }
  echo $output;
}
```

In my post page

```
<?php fragment_cache('text' . $post->ID, WEEK_IN_SECONDS, function() {  ?>
    <?php the_sub_field('text'); ?>
<?php }); ?>
```

In my menu:

```
<?php 
    fragment_cache('primary-nav', YEAR_IN_SECONDS, function() {
        wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) );
    });
?>
```

Comment: Add the code you are using to your question.

Comment: do multiple subsequent requests contain the same number of queries? you'll have more queries on requests where the transient doesn't yet exist, or is being refreshed, but after that initial transient population, they should go down if the number of requests to build the transients is greater than the number of requests to fetch the transients.

Comment: The issue is precisely that the requests do not seem to go down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using transient API which works storing data on `wp_options` table by default. That means that additional database queries will be performed to set the transient and to get the transient. With your code the number of queries should be less for non-logged in users in second and subsequent visits when the transient exists and it is valid.

If you use a persistent cache plugin (or you configure persistent cache at your own) the transient API will use [WP_Object_Cache](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache) allowing the cached data be stored in memory instead of database, so there won't be extra database queries.

**Summary**: using wp_cache functions will store cached data on memory and it is not persistent by default. In the other hand, transient API is persistent always and it use database by default. If you configure persistent cache, transient API and [WP_Object_Cache](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache) return same results as transient API will use [WP_Object_Cache](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One thing I don't get though.If I have a transient containing 10 db calls, it's ok if the first time i get 12 db calls, but why shouldn't I get only 2 calls the second time around? I still get a lot.

Comment: I'm sorry but with the information you have provided I can not know. To answer that question a closer debug of your site is needed, which is out of the scope of WPSE. Also, note that in your code you are bypassing the transient cache for logged in users, so you must visit the site logged out to see the cache effects.

Comment: I will try setting up a twentyfifteen theme and see if the same happens. Many thanks